# How to manipulate a float value which starts from .somevalue to 0.somevalue in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box where user enters numbers which are mostly in float data type . This value is then added to some previous value .
When a user adds float number like `0.123` it is added fine but when he adds it like `.123` it throws error Nan .
I am using following code.

```
var labor_cost = Number($("#labor_cost").val());
            var other_cost = Number($("#other_cost").val());
            var profitValue = Number($("#profitValue").val());
            var ingCost = Number($("#productTotalcost").val());
            profitAmount = ((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost)*profitValue/100);                
            $("#showproposedprice").html((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost+Number(profitAmount)).toFixed(2));                                                    
            $("#proposedprice").val((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost+Number(profitAmount)).toFixed(4));
```

Please help me how can I skip or manipulate a float number `.123` to `0.123` ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code. That shouldn't normally happen. `.123` is a perfectly fine float value.

Comment: `parseFloat(".123")` returns `0.123`.

Comment: As does `+".123"`, or any other operation that coerces the string to a number.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: I have tried your code, and cannot reproduce the error.  Here is what I have done (including HTML), with an updated Fiddle.  Can you reproduce the error in the Fiddle?  If so, then let me know what you are putting in each text box.  If not, compare your code to this and see what's different:

```
<p>Labour cost: <input type="text" id="labor_cost" /></p>
<p>Other cost: <input type="text" id="other_cost" /></p>
<p>Profit Value: <input type="text" id="profitValue" /></p>
<p>Product Total Cost: <input type="text" id="productTotalcost" /></p>
<button id="submit">click</button>

<hr/>
<p>Show Proposed Price: <span id="showproposedprice"></span></p>
<p>Proposed Price: <input type="text" id="proposedprice" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var labor_cost = Number($("#labor_cost").val());
    var other_cost = Number($("#other_cost").val());
    var profitValue = Number($("#profitValue").val());
    var ingCost = Number($("#productTotalcost").val());
    var profitAmount = ((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost)*profitValue/100);
    $("#showproposedprice").html((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost+Number(profitAmount)).toFixed(2));                                                    
    $("#proposedprice").val((ingCost+other_cost+labor_cost+Number(profitAmount)).toFixed(4));
  })
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8xburf6/2/